# Only first part of string in input fields of form

Tags: flask

I have a flask app with a database including books as a table.
I get a string from a HTML form and do a query on the db:

```
 if request.method == "POST":
        if "btn_book_search" in request.form:
            search_title = request.form["search_title"]
            search_result = db.session.execute(
                text("SELECT * FROM Buecher WHERE Titel LIKE :s"),
                {"s": "%" + search_title + "%"},
            ).fetchall()
            print(search_result)
            return render_template("book_management.html", books=search_result)
```

The console through `print(search_result)` shows the records with the full title - several words with spaces between.

The HTML file looks - for testing purpose - like this:

```
      <div class="col-7">
        <h2>Suchergebnisse</h2>
        {% if books %}
           <input type="text" id="test0" value={{books[0].Titel}}>
           {{books[0].Titel}}
        {% endif %}
        {% for book in books %}
           <input type="text" id="test2" value={{books[0].Titel}}>
           {{books[0].Titel}}
           <input type="text" id="test2" value={{book.Titel}}>
           {{book.Titel}}
           <form action="" method="POST">
             <input type="text" id="test3" value={{book.Titel}}>
             <textarea class="form-control" id="test4" readonly>{{book.Titel}}</textarea>
```

The test shows: ALL Input fields only show the first word of the title, cutting at the first space. ALL sole parameters in {{}} and the text area show the complete title.

Where is the bug? Flask? Me?

I'm out of options as I don't know what went wrong.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should enclose the `value` parameters of the input fields in double quotes, then the whole title should appear.

```html
<input type="text" id="test0" value="{{books[0].Titel}}" />
```